# Find and show array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

For a while I'm trying to show the contents of an array with jade but I did not get anything here I leave my code

```
var array = new Schema({
    prueba:String
})

var img_schema= new Schema({
    title:{type:String, require:true},
    creator:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User" },
    extension:{type:String,require:true},
    name:{type:String, require:true},
    array:[array]
});
```

To save the data

```
var data = {
    title: req.body.title,
    creator:res.locals.user._id,
    extension:extension,
    name:req.body.archivo.name,
    array:{prueba:"hola"}
}
```

How do I display the data

```
each user in imagen
    p #{user.array.prueba}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data, you are passing an object instead of an array. Make it an array like this:

```
var data = {
    // ...
    array: [{prueba:"hola"}]
}
```

Then in your jade template, you'll probably want to loop through the array like this:

```
each user in imagen
    each prueba in user.array
        p #{prueba}
```